# Arrow thickness not changing when using line styles extension in xypic

Tags: arrows, width, xy-pic

I'm trying to make some of my arrows thicker in Latex with xypic.  In the following example that I designed using http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf, the second arrow should be ten times as thick as the first.  This does not seem to work.  Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}         
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix
{
A\ar[r]&B\\
A\ar@*{[|(10)]}[r]&B\\
}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the warning `Xy-pic Warning: The linewidth 3.99979pt effect is not implemented with the current driver`

Comment: Thanks, @egreg!  Yes, this is the error that I'm getting too.  The question is how do I select a driver that will implement the linewidth specification, or give it a line width that it can deal with?

Comment: I think there is *no* driver supporting it. Anyway, you're bound to either the PDF or DVIPS driver.